# needed help on list() and sort() funcion

Tags: python

I am a complete newbie to Python and am completely stuck. Basically, I have information in a list like the one below:

```
[a, b, c, d]

[e, f, g, h, i]
```

and so on....

From each list I want to get the second and the final data, so that it will return the following

```
b,d
f,i
```

I have been looking at using the sort() function or the split() function but to be honest I have no idea where to start.

Please can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the "second" and "final" data? Extracting an item from a list by position/index is straight forward...basic Python know how

Comment: for each list `lst`, you get the second element with `lst[1]`, and the last one with `lst[-1]`

Comment: -1 for asking a poor and very basic question

Answer (score 3):

```
for lis in lists:
    print(lis[1], lis[-1])
```

Where `[1]` gives the second element and `[-1]` gives the last. List indices start at `0`, which is why `[1]` gives the second element. Negative indices are valid as well, and starting from `-1`, they count backwards from the end of the list. Negative indices are especially useful when dealing with lists of variable lengths.

In your case `lists` would be `[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h, i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
# Assuming the letters below actually have values,
# otherwise you must make these characters
mylist = [a,b,c,d]

secondElement = mylist[1]
lastElement = mylist[-1]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Oops - almost missed that! Thanks for pointing out... have edited my answer.

P.S. - vote it up! :)

Answer (score 0):

`list[-1]` will return the last element of the list, and `list[1]` will return the second element of the list
something like

```
>>>a = [1,2,3,4]
>>>b = [5,6,7,8]

>>>print a[1],a[-1]
4,2
>>>print b[1],b[-1]
6,8

index from left:  0, 1, 2, 3
list           : [5, 2, 2, 4]
index fro right: -4,-3,-2,-1
```